# Looping in ForEach, but what is the Variable

Tags: c#, foreach, configurationmanager

I have a logging app that is malfunctioning and I am working on the console line to test out my code. When I realized since I am getting the infor from COnfigurationManager i don't know what the variable in my FOR Each is called ?

```
string machineNamesConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MachineNames"];
var machineNames = new List<string>(machineNamesConfig.Split(','));
machineNames = machineNames.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
foreach (??? m in machineNames)
{

}
```

Comment: You're iterating over a List of Strings, so in this case it would be a string m in machineNames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, the variable is called "m".

What you're looking for is the *type* of the variable.  You can let the compiler infer that by using `var` as in Mike Schwartz's answer.  You can also use `string` because you know that `machineNames` is a list of strings:

```
foreach (string m in machineNames)
{
    //...
}
```

The type of the variable declared in the foreach loop can be `var`, or it can be the element type of the collection you're iterating, or it can be any subtype of the element type.  There's probably not a good reason for doing it, but if you want you could also do one of the following:

```
foreach (object m in machineNames) { }
foreach (IEnumerable<char> m in machineNames) { }
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 foreach (var m in machineNames)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a `List<string>` at the second line of your code, then ordering it and then creating a list again.

Following that, the type of the objects inside the `machineNames` list should be `string`.

Anyways, you can also use var and forget about the type, as the compiler will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is better, and preferable since you are iterating List of strings even though you assign your objects to var variable `machineNames`, it is still `string`, just you are lazy to define the proper variable. In addition, it gives a sense if somebody look at your code, at first glance, he will know what you are iterating.

```
foreach (string m in machineNames)
 {

 }
```

the following also works.

```
foreach (var m in machineNames)
 {

 }
```

**Quick note:** using `var` over `string` is no difference. It's really just a coding style. The compiler generates the exact same for both variants. There is also no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this whole thing as a one liner:

```
foreach (var machineName in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MachineNames"].Split(',').OrderBy(i => i)) 
{

}
```

And as everyone suggested, var is interchangeable with string.

Comment: `Split (',') ` is missing!